# Parallel resistor across inductor practical model - switching converter

Tags: analog, dc-dc-converter, inductor, switching, pmic

[image]

While designing switching converter, I have included the inductor practical model as shown in the image. Since Rvar2 is small value and in the order of milli-ohm. I see it is impacting my circuit behavior. What is the design practice to get rid of this.

Comment: Rvar2 in miliohms is very poor inductor.

Comment: Please post the source of your graphics.

Answer (score 2):

The equations apply for a minimum of 100kHz frequency, and frequency is in Hz, so Rvar2 would be a minimum of about 84Ω. At that low a frequency the reactance of the 1.5uH inductance is <1Ω.

If you attempt to use this model outside of the [valid region](https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/f781ec7c-521b-48c6-b53f-5d64dfcde69c/spice_xgl4030.pdf) you'll get bad results (emphasis added):

> This lumped-element (SPICE) model data simulates the
> frequency-dependent behavior of Coilcraft power inductors **within the
> frequency range shown in the accompanying table** for each individual
> inductor